# IntelliSense: a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double"

Tags: c++, methods, vector, intellisense

So, I've deleted and retyped the line the error refers to, closed and reopened visual studio, and looked through several errors posted here that show the same/similar wording as mine.

I have a feeling this is an error with visual studio, because even after I deleted everything code-wise, saved, and recompiled, it gave an error on the same line that no longer existed.

> ### "IntelliSense: a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double""

Just in case it's not an error with studio, I thought I'd ask for any ideas as to what in my code could be causing this error? The blockquote in the middle of the code is the line that it references with that error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   //Declarations of vectors and basic holders for input transfer
   vector<string> candidateName;
   string inputString;
   vector<int> candidateVotes;
   int counter,inputInt,totaledVotes;
   double percentage;
   vector<double> candidatePercentage;
   //Method declaration for calculations
   void calculatePercentage (int, int, int);

   //User input to gather number of candidates, names, and votes received.
   cout <<"How many candidates need to be input?";
   cin>>counter;
   for(int i = 0;i<counter;i++)
   {
      cout<<"Please enter the candidate's last name.";
      cin>>inputString;
      candidateName.push_back(inputString);
      cout<<"Please enter the number of votes "<<candidateName[i]<<" received.";
      cin>>inputInt;
      candidateVotes.push_back(inputInt);
      totaledVotes+=candidateVotes[i];
   }
   for(int i = 0;i<counter;i++)
   {
      //Problem here vvv
      percentage = calculatePercentage(totaledVotes, candidateVotes[i], i);
      //Problem there ^^^

      candidatePercentage.push_back(percentage);
   }
}

double calculatePercentage (int totalVotes, int candidateVotes, int rosterNumber)
{
   int percentage;
   percentage = candidateVotes/totalVotes;
   percentage*=100;
   return percentage;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have this declaration

```
void calculatePercentage (int, int, int);
```

Then you do

```
percentage = calculatePercentage(totaledVotes, candidateVotes[i], i);
```

But you just declared that the function doesn't return anything.

And it also doesn't match the actual definition later:

```
double calculatePercentage (int totalVotes, int candidateVotes, int rosterNumber)
```

Comment: I feel stupid now. I changed the method, and completely forgot about the declaration. I miss Java. Thanks!

Comment: And you edited out the fact that the declaration didn't match the definition.  Why?  It is (IMHO, at least) an important point as well.  (An interesting point, too, is that because of the C++ scoping rules, the erroneous declaration isn't visible at the point where the definition occurs.  A good compiler might catch it anyway, but the results are undefined behavior, and not an error requiring a diagnostic.  Yet another reason never to put function declarations inside another function.)

Answer (score 2):

You declare the function returning `void`:

```
void calculatePercentage (int, int, int);
```

That should be `double` to match the later definition and usage.